# Implementing variable in id

Tags: javascript, html, variables

[image]

Is there a way to implement variable 'o' instead of '1' in #po_am_1 ? Thank you.

```
var pondeli_in = [];
var o = 0;
$('input[name="pondeli"]:checked').each(function () {
   pondeli_in.push(($(this).attr('value')) + (' (') + ($('#po_am_1').val()) + ('x)') + ("<br>"));
   o += 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 template literals or string concatenation. Pick one.

```
$(`#po_am_${o}`)

$('#po_am_' + o)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can avoid using an extra variable for index

```js
var pondeli_in = [];
$('input[name="pondeli"]:checked').each(function (i, el) {
    pondeli_in.push(($(el).attr('value')) + (' (') + ($('#po_am_' + i).val()) + ('x)') + ("<br>"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can. with string interpolation.

```
$(`#po_am_${o}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var pondeli_in = [];
var o = 0;
$('input[name="pondeli"]:checked').each(function () {
   pondeli_in.push(($(this).attr('value')) + (' (') + ($('#po_am_'+o).val()) + ('x)') + ("<br>"));
   o += 1;
});
```